# Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method

Tags: groovy

Simple code: `ClosuresSyntax.groovy`

```
{ -> item++ }
{ item -> item++ }
```

it cause an exception:

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:  
       com.lucaslee.groovy.syntax.ClosuresSyntax$_run_closure1.call()      is applicable for argument types:
(com.lucaslee.groovy.syntax.ClosuresSyntax$_run_closure2) values: 
    [com.lucaslee.groovy.syntax.ClosuresSyntax$_run_closure2@1534f01b]
```

Comment: Does my answer solve the problem? If so, please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is the same as (note the parentheses):

```
{ -> item++}({ item -> item++})
```

The definition of both closures is fully correct. The problem is that in fact the first closure is run with the second one passed as an argument. This is exactly the same:

```
{ it -> it() } { println 1 }
```

Since you can't invoke `++` on a `Closure` object `MissingMethodException` is thrown. This will work correctly e.g.:

```
{ item -> item()++ }{ 1 }
```

A closure `{1}` is passed as an argument, invoked `()` and a result is incremented `++`.

To verify that closures definitions are correct, run:

```
def a = { -> item++ }
def b = { item -> item++ }
```